# 18.04 monitor is off after waking up

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, suspend, screen, monitor

After waking up from suspend screen remains off.

Everything else works, system isn't hanged.

System is up-to-date, kernel version is latest - 4.15.0.46.

I have Desktop with following hardware:

1. AMD Athlon CPU
2. NVidia PCI-e card.
3. MSI AM1I motherboard.

BIOS has no option to turn off integrated AMD GPU.

Graphics drivers are "proprietary, tested" (as they say) nvidia-390.

nouveau is NOT loaded. (as gpu-manager says)

amdgpu is NOT loaded. (as gpu-manager says)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install 18.04 in UEFI mode. Affects 18.10 as well.